# Spring Service instance variable in a multi-threaded environment

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, thread-safety

I recently ran into a race condition issue because of declaring an instance variable inside a default scoped (Singleton scope) Service class.  The purpose of the instance variable was to make my code more readable and avoid the constant passing of the same variable to different private methods within the Service class. The example goes:

```
@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {
    private final StatusRepository statusRepository;
    private Predicate<Status> statusPredicate;

    @Autowired
    public SomeServiceImpl(StatusRepository statusRepository) {
        this.statusRepository = statusRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Status> getAllowedStatuses(String userId) {
        statuses = statusRepository.getAll();
        initPredicate();
        appendPredicateA();
        appendPredicateB();
        List<Status> results = statuses.stream()
            .filter(statusPredicate)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return results;
    }

    private void initPredicate() {
        statusPredicate = p -> p.getDefault().equals("default");
    }

    private void appendPredicateA() {
        statusPredicate.and(p -> p.getA().equals("A"));
    }

    private void appendPredicateB() {
        statusPredicate.and(p -> p.getB().equals("B"));
    }
}
```

This is a very simple example of the kind of things I want to achieve. This is clearly not thread-safe because now the service class is stateful.  I could simply resolve this by turning the ***statusPredicate*** variable into a local variable and have the ***void*** methods return the predicate after it has been appended new conditions, but that would become cluttered like this:

```
@Override
public List<Status> getAllowedStatuses(String userId) {
    statuses = statusRepository.getAll();
    Predicate<Status> statusPredicate = p -> p.getDefault().equals("default");
    statusPredicate = appendPredicateA(statusPredicate);
    statusPredicate = appendPredicateB(statusPredicate);
    List<Status> results = statuses.stream()
        .filter(statusPredicate)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return results;
}
```

It'd be constantly calling to modify the variable and return the variable.

I know a few solutions that can resolve this such as adding ***@RequestScope*** on the Service class to ensure each request from the HTTP will get a new instance of the 
Service object, or use ***ThreadLocal*** on the Predicate variable.  However, I'm not quite certain what is the best approach and whether declaring an instance variable in a Service class is even okay to begin with.  If it is bad to make Service class stateful to begin with, how should I structure my code to make it cleaner and still keeping it stateless?

Please advise! Thanks in advance :D

Comment: It is in fact bad to make a service class stateful for exactly the reasons you suspect. It really usually is best to go with your other option, which really isn't that bad. If you start getting a lot of custom predicates, you can always put those in a list and iterate over that list.

Comment: the original code is not bad and can be written more succinctly. the options under consideration are all worse.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks for the advice! :D

Comment: @NathanHughes Could you elaborate a little bit on why the options under consideration are all worse? Is it because they violate the contract of a singleton and potential unnecessary complexity that arise from the use of _ThreadLocal_? Also, could you provide a little example on how to write the example code more succinctly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Spring Service can be stateful and this is why scopes for.

Default scope of Spring Service is Singleton because this is the widest use case. But you shouldn't use mutable local variables.

Simply, try for a stateless design and use scopes to solve the issue only if the class instantiation is fast otherwise TreadLocal will perform better.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  In the example, I wanted to separate the three filters into three private methods and each filter is applied when a condition is met (basic if-statements).  If I use a Singleton scope and not using the ThreadLocal for the class variable, I need to make the variable local.  And in that case, it has to be a mutable local variable as each of the filters may or may not be applied.  How do I go about and achieve that as I do not want to reassign the local variable each time a filter applies.  What are the better solutions to make this code more elegant and effective?